# Duplicate row values in Birt

Tags: java, birt

Am having cube I want to remove duplicate entries in birt Cube .Problem is when previous column is having more than one non duplicate records then next column is giving duplicates.Please help me to achieve this.

Image below is current output.

```
1 part1 10.000000@2013.03.24 1.000000@31/07/2013 
                             5.000000@22/07/2013 
2 part2 10.000000@2013.07.23 1.000000@31/07/2013 
        50.000000@2013.07.22 1.000000@31/07/2013 
        50.000000@2013.07.24 1.000000@31/07/2013
```

Expected Output :

```
1 part1 10.000000@2013.03.24 1.000000@31/07/2013 
                             5.000000@22/07/2013 
2 part2 10.000000@2013.07.23 1.000000@31/07/2013 
        50.000000@2013.07.22 
        50.000000@2013.07.24
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this exception select the table column and in the general properties click the Suppress duplicates checkbox.For more details view [this](http://birtworld.blogspot.in/2010/10/birt-duplicate-rows.html) tutorial of avoiding duplicate columns.

Cheers